# Need help to Create Circular List view

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to create a circular list view (After scrolling to the Last element Its start showing First element and go on) in android But i didn't found any help on web for the same. I just want to know is their any default property/component in Android to support circular list view or i need to create custom list view by putting some logic for the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this [circular-list-adapter](https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/circular-list-adapter)

Comment: if we want circular list for horizontal listview?

Answer (score 0):

If using LoadersCallbacks I have created MyCircularCursor class which wraps the typical cursor like this:

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> pCursorLoader, Cursor pCursor) {
        mItemListAdapter.swapCursor(new MyCircularCursor(pCursor));
}
```

the decorator class code is here:

```
/**
 * {@link MyCircularCursor}<br/>
 * <br/>
 * @author Vilius Kraujutis
 * @since 31 Jan 2013 02:09:48
 *
 */
public class MyCircularCursor implements Cursor {

private Cursor mCursor;

/**
 * @param pCursor
 */
public MyCircularCursor(Cursor pCursor) {
    mCursor = pCursor;
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.database.Cursor#getCount()
 */
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mCursor.getCount() == 0 ? 0 : Integer.MAX_VALUE;
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.database.Cursor#getPosition()
 */
@Override
public int getPosition() {
    return mCursor.getPosition();
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.database.Cursor#move(int)
 */
@Override
public boolean move(int pOffset) {
    return mCursor.move(pOffset);
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.database.Cursor#moveToPosition(int)
 */
@Override
public boolean moveToPosition(int pPosition) {
    int position = MathUtils.mod(pPosition, mCursor.getCount());
    return mCursor.moveToPosition(position);
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.database.Cursor#moveToFirst()
 */
@Override
public boolean moveToFirst() {
    return mCursor.moveToFirst();
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.database.Cursor#moveToLast()
 */
@Override
public boolean moveToLast() {
    return mCursor.moveToLast();
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.database.Cursor#moveToNext()
 */
@Override
public boolean moveToNext() {
    if (mCursor.isLast()) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
        return true;
    } else {
        return mCursor.moveToNext();
    }
    // return mCursor.moveToNext();
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.database.Cursor#moveToPrevious()
 */
@Override
public boolean moveToPrevious() {
    if (mCursor.isFirst()) {
        mCursor.moveToLast();
        return true;
    } else {
        return mCursor.moveToPrevious();
    }
    // return mCursor.moveToPrevious();
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.database.Cursor#isFirst()
 */
@Override
public boolean isFirst() {
    // return mCursor.isFirst();
    return false;
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.database.Cursor#isLast()
 */
@Override
public boolean isLast() {
    return false;
    // return mCursor.isLast();
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.database.Cursor#isBeforeFirst()
 */
@Override
public boolean isBeforeFirst() {
    return false;
    // return mCursor.isBeforeFirst();
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.database.Cursor#isAfterLast()
 */
@Override
public boolean isAfterLast() {
    return false;
    // return mCursor.isAfterLast();
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.database.Cursor#getColumnIndex(java.lang.String)
 */
@Override
public int getColumnIndex(String pColumnName) {
    return mCursor.getColumnIndex(pColumnName);
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.database.Cursor#getColumnIndexOrThrow(java.lang.String)
 */
@Override
public int getColumnIndexOrThrow(String pColumnName) throws IllegalArgumentException {

    return mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(pColumnName);
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.database.Cursor#getColumnName(int)
 */
@Override
public String getColumnName(int pColumnIndex) {

    return mCursor.getColumnName(pColumnIndex);
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.database.Cursor#getColumnNames()
 */
@Override
public String[] getColumnNames() {

    return mCursor.getColumnNames();
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.database.Cursor#getColumnCount()
 */
@Override
public int getColumnCount() {

    return mCursor.getColumnCount();
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.database.Cursor#getBlob(int)
 */
@Override
public byte[] getBlob(int pColumnIndex) {

    return mCursor.getBlob(pColumnIndex);
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.database.Cursor#getString(int)
 */
@Override
public String getString(int pColumnIndex) {

    return mCursor.getString(pColumnIndex);
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.database.Cursor#getShort(int)
 */
@Override
public short getShort(int pColumnIndex) {

    return mCursor.getShort(pColumnIndex);
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.database.Cursor#getInt(int)
 */
@Override
public int getInt(int pColumnIndex) {

    return mCursor.getInt(pColumnIndex);
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.database.Cursor#getLong(int)
 */
@Override
public long getLong(int pColumnIndex) {

    return mCursor.getLong(pColumnIndex);
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.database.Cursor#getFloat(int)
 */
@Override
public float getFloat(int pColumnIndex) {

    return mCursor.getFloat(pColumnIndex);
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.database.Cursor#getDouble(int)
 */
@Override
public double getDouble(int pColumnIndex) {

    return mCursor.getDouble(pColumnIndex);
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.database.Cursor#getType(int)
 */
@Override
public int getType(int pColumnIndex) {
    // return mCursor.getType(pColumnIndex);
    return 0;
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.database.Cursor#isNull(int)
 */
@Override
public boolean isNull(int pColumnIndex) {

    return mCursor.isNull(pColumnIndex);
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.database.Cursor#deactivate()
 */
@Override
public void deactivate() {
    mCursor.deactivate();
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.database.Cursor#requery()
 */
@Override
@Deprecated
public boolean requery() {

    return mCursor.requery();
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.database.Cursor#close()
 */
@Override
public void close() {
    mCursor.close();
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.database.Cursor#isClosed()
 */
@Override
public boolean isClosed() {

    return mCursor.isClosed();
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.database.Cursor#registerContentObserver(android.database.ContentObserver)
 */
@Override
public void registerContentObserver(ContentObserver pObserver) {
    mCursor.registerContentObserver(pObserver);
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.database.Cursor#unregisterContentObserver(android.database.ContentObserver)
 */
@Override
public void unregisterContentObserver(ContentObserver pObserver) {
    mCursor.unregisterContentObserver(pObserver);
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.database.Cursor#registerDataSetObserver(android.database.DataSetObserver)
 */
@Override
public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver pObserver) {
    mCursor.registerDataSetObserver(pObserver);
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.database.Cursor#unregisterDataSetObserver(android.database.DataSetObserver)
 */
@Override
public void unregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver pObserver) {
    mCursor.unregisterDataSetObserver(pObserver);
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.database.Cursor#setNotificationUri(android.content.ContentResolver,
 * android.net.Uri)
 */
@Override
public void setNotificationUri(ContentResolver pCr, Uri pUri) {
    mCursor.setNotificationUri(pCr, pUri);
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.database.Cursor#getWantsAllOnMoveCalls()
 */
@Override
public boolean getWantsAllOnMoveCalls() {

    return mCursor.getWantsAllOnMoveCalls();
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.database.Cursor#getExtras()
 */
@Override
public Bundle getExtras() {

    return mCursor.getExtras();
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.database.Cursor#respond(android.os.Bundle)
 */
@Override
public Bundle respond(Bundle pExtras) {

    return mCursor.respond(pExtras);
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.database.Cursor#copyStringToBuffer(int, android.database.CharArrayBuffer)
 */
@Override
public void copyStringToBuffer(int pColumnIndex, CharArrayBuffer pBuffer) {
    mCursor.copyStringToBuffer(pColumnIndex, pBuffer);

}

}
```